# Matlab GUI Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Tags: matlab-guide, handles

I have a GUI menu on Matlab with 4 buttons (menu.fig). Then I have 4 .fig file that I want to open when I click on the buttons. Here it's all ok, when I open a .fig from menu and insert value to do a plot I get this error:

> ???? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

If I try to open 1.fig directly, everything works perfectly.

I read that the problem is with eval(), but I can't solve it.

I changed the variable names on each .fig file

One 1.fig:

```
function pbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
A1=get(handles.edtSAmp,'String');
f1=get(handles.edtSFreq, 'String');
fi1=get(handles.edtSFase, 'String');
t1=get(handles.popTipo, 'Value');

A1=str2double(A1);
f1=str2double(f1);
fi=str2double(fi1);

SinalSinusoidal(A1,f1,fi,t1);
```

I got the error on the that 1st line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is something MATLAB GUI not handled well. I know it used to work, but when you tweaking your UI or UI related code a bit and accidentally you modified some area MATLAB told you not to touch, this kind of issue begin to happen.

**The workaournd is to start the GUI from M editor by clicking run**

I know it works, but originally, when I directly lauch it , it works too. so, this is not the end of it, people are just not getting to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with probably with `handles1`. It's not a structure array like you expect it to be. In GUI's created with GUIDE, this variable is usually called `handles`, if you have both `handles` and `handles1` make sure `handles1` contains handles to the objects in the figure. If you're using `handles1` only, make sure you're initializing it properly.

Comment: I changed it to try, with handles it doesn't work too.. I'll correct that on the question.

Comment: Did you change it everywhere in your code? Was this GUI made with GUIDE?

Comment: I only changed it when I got that error, then I undo the changes. Yes it's made with GUIDE.

Comment: If you're getting that error on the first line, handles is not a structure. Maybe it's overwritten somewhere. Are you using guidata with handles1?

Comment: Probably not. Hard to tell without seeing everything. guidata can overwrite your handles structure if used improperly.